# Make Temporary MariaDB User Passwords

Tags: mariadb

After I establish and user and set their password, is there a way to have users reset their passwords on login?  I'd like the password I set for them to be temporary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you sign up your user, make something that says that their password is temporary (such as a field in the database that's an int with either 0 or 1).  When they log in, it should check the field for if the password is temporary, and if it is, then ask them for their real password and use [the UPDATE statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) to update their password.  If it isn't, continue normally.